# Accessing Children in Json Array of Objects

Tags: json, react-native, children

Created a Mock Json server and able to access it via localhost:3000/JOBS.
How do I access the children "Parcels"  in URL like accessing the type of open like localhost:3000/JOBS?type=open. Thanks in advance.

I have a Json Array of objects as below:

```
{
  "JOBS": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "type": "open",
      "driver": "Andy",
      "receiver": "Paul",
      "price": "635.50",

      "Parcels": [
        {
          "parcelId": "90"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you cant access only `Parcels` as is.

You need to modify your tree structure, in order to access `Parcels` as

```
{
    "JOBS": [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "type": "open",
            "driver": "Andy",
            "receiver": "Paul",
            "price": "635.50"
        }
    ],
    "PARCELS": [
        {
            "parcelId": "90"
        }
    ]
}
```

and access it as  `localhost:3000/PARCELS` as mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/359) and described [here](http://my-json-server.typicode.com/pritishvaidya/demo/PARCELS)

Comment: Thank you , but i need Parcels inside JOBS , this seems to be another new array and not children

Comment: You need to make a separate array for `Parcels` and link them to `Job` by it's unique id or `Job ID`.